# Improvements for the UI

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As known, there's a high rate of unanswered Qs. Maybe the following improvements help lowering their number:

1. Show accept rate in "Questions" list view: Would make it much easier to search for people that need to get pushed to "work" on their open Qs.
2. Standard/pre defined comment with a) a link to how to ask a Q and b) push them to (again) "work" on their accept rate/open Qs.
3. Automagically search the post title & content for words that are in the list of tags and auto suggest them: Priority is title > content. Multiple matches higher the priority for a single tag. Maybe also weight the number of Qs that are attached to a tag (higher number equals higher priority).
4. Show last answer/comment from an answerer, last activity from the OP and the time difference at single Q view. Makes it also easier to ask for further progress, close vote or continue with new efforts to solve the Q.

Comment: [Perfect example of a question that has no business still being opened](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7292/critical-error-in-final-stage-of-website-launch-urls-are-broken). It was answered in the comments, and the commenter never went back to add the comment as an answer. Perhaps someone can ping @OneTrickPony and have him post his comment as an answer?

Comment: @Chip Pony is pathological commenter... :)

Comment: So, I know mods can *move answers to comments*; can you do the reverse: *move comments to new answers*?

Comment: @Chip unfortunately no. I think this have been asked for on main meta, but I don't know if it's going to be implemented (not so far).

Answer (score 2):

> Show accept rate in "Questions" list view: Would make it much easier to search for people that need to get pushed to "work" on their open Qs.

Not sure. List view should focus on specific question, not person asking. User with perfect accept rate can ask crappy question, just as user with zero accept rate can ask good one.

> Standard/pre defined comment with a) a link to how to ask a Q and b) push them to (again) "work" on their accept rate/open Qs.

This would make more sense as more informational message on close.

> Automagically search the post title & content for words that are in the list of tags and auto suggest them: Priority is title > content. Multiple matches higher the priority for a single tag. Maybe also weight the number of Qs that are attached to a tag (higher number equals higher priority).

Depends on implementation. `wordress-*` was such a plague exactly because of auto-suggest examples. Double-edged sword.

> Show last answer/comment from an answerer, last activity from the OP and the time difference at single Q view. Makes it also easier to ask for further progress, close vote or continue with new efforts to solve the Q.

I am not sure how answer/comment would fit in. Time since last activity would make sense.

Comment: Ad "Show last answer/comment") Yes, I meant difference between last activity of OP & answerer. Ad Tags) Higher rep level users would then IMHO take more care about tags and synonyms. Haven't we had some discussion about "reserved/locked/not assignable" tags already (like "wordpress" or "help"). Ad "Standard comment"-a.) I wouldn't close that soon. It was meant more like: "Please define your Q more in detail". Ad "Accept rate") Agree.

Comment: @kaiser we got WP tags banned, but I would like to not risk create new epidemic of some crappy tag(s). :) On commenting - that means coming back later to check up and eats unholy amount of time. Lately I've been moving to closing much more aggressively, OP can always comment/flag with re-open request but the fact is that most don't ever care or bother to improve their questions. I'd rather spend time re-opening one question that got improved than stalking dozens that won't ever be.

Comment: Accepted. Let's hope there comes someone from SE and takes a look & comments.